# How to fix this Tailwind CSS RTL floating labels margin issue?

Tags: css, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui, flowbite

I've copied the floating labels block from [flowbite here](https://flowbite.com/docs/forms/floating-label/) to make this sample test.

The problem that the code is working fine in LRT direction, however if we switch to RTL direction it will miss up lable **spaceing from start or the start margin is incorrect it's not equal to when in LTR direction**! please click the `switch to` in the sample below and check it out.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Test Sample</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flowbite/2.2.1/flowbite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flowbite/2.2.1/flowbite.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>

  <div class="flex min-h-full flex-col justify-center px-6 py-12 lg:px-8">
    <div class="sm:mx-auto sm:w-full sm:max-w-sm">
      <h2 class="mt-10 text-center text-2xl font-bold leading-9 tracking-tight text-gray-900">test page</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="mt-10 sm:mx-auto sm:w-full sm:max-w-sm">
      <div class="space-y-6">

        <div class="relative">
          <input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="floating_outlined" class="block px-2.5 pb-2.5 pt-4 w-full text-sm text-gray-900 bg-transparent rounded-lg border border-gray-300 appearance-none focus:outline-none focus:ring-0 focus:border-blue-600 peer" placeholder=" "
          />
          <label for="floating_outlined" class="absolute text-sm text-gray-500 duration-200 transform -translate-y-4 scale-75 top-2 z-10 origin-[0] bg-white px-2 peer-focus:px-2 peer-focus:text-blue-600  peer-placeholder-shown:scale-100 peer-placeholder-shown:-translate-y-1/2 peer-placeholder-shown:top-1/2 peer-focus:top-2 peer-focus:scale-75 peer-focus:-translate-y-4 rtl:peer-focus:translate-x-1/4 rtl:peer-focus:left-auto start-1">My Floating Label (1)</label>
        </div>

        <div class="relative">
          <input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="floating_outlined" class="block px-2.5 pb-2.5 pt-4 w-full text-sm text-gray-900 bg-transparent rounded-lg border border-gray-300 appearance-none  focus:outline-none focus:ring-0 focus:border-blue-600 peer" placeholder=" "
            value="This is a test" />
          <label for="floating_outlined" class="absolute text-sm text-gray-500 duration-200 transform -translate-y-4 scale-75 top-2 z-10 origin-[0] bg-white px-2 peer-focus:px-2 peer-focus:text-blue-600  peer-placeholder-shown:scale-100 peer-placeholder-shown:-translate-y-1/2 peer-placeholder-shown:top-1/2 peer-focus:top-2 peer-focus:scale-75 peer-focus:-translate-y-4 rtl:peer-focus:translate-x-1/4 rtl:peer-focus:left-auto start-1">My Floating Label (2)</label>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="mt-8 text-center text-sm text-gray-500">
        <a>Switch To:</a>
        <a id="lng" class="font-semibold leading-6 text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-500 cursor-pointer" onclick="switchLang()">RTL</a>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    // Function to switch the language
    function switchLang() {

      if (document.getElementById('lng').innerHTML == 'RTL') {

        document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].style.direction = 'rtl';
        document.getElementById('lng').innerHTML = 'LTR';

      } else {

        document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].style.direction = 'ltr';
        document.getElementById('lng').innerHTML = 'RTL';
      }
    };
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

I tried to fix that by many ways like adding negative margins for only when in RTL but it doesn't work however it made it worse, maybe there is something else that I don't know is happing.

any fix for that please?

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for all HTML tags.

Comment: @Rob it was just there in their web site I did not change anything... check the link :)

Comment: You would think the Tailwind people would at least make an attempt at following web standards or at least take a passing glance at them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd want to switch the `dir` attribute of the `<html>` element, not apply `direction` style for the `rtl:` Tailwind variant to match:

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].dir = 'rtl';
```

Then to have the floating label have the equivalent position in RTL as it does LTR, change the `transform-origin` from `0` to `right`. This can be done via the `rtl:origin-right` class. For the purposes of the inline snippet below, I've had to use the [`!important` modifier](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#important-modifier) with this class since otherwise the Flowbite CDN CSS would override the rule.

Also, you seem to have some invalid HTML, `</Label></label>` – consider removing the capitalized end tag.

```js
// Function to switch the language
function switchLang() {

  if (document.getElementById('lng').innerHTML == 'RTL') {

    document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].dir = 'rtl';
    document.getElementById('lng').innerHTML = 'LTR';

  } else {

    document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].dir = 'ltr';
    document.getElementById('lng').innerHTML = 'RTL';
  }
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Test Sample</title>

  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flowbite/2.2.1/flowbite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flowbite/2.2.1/flowbite.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>

  <div class="flex min-h-full flex-col justify-center px-6 py-12 lg:px-8">
    <div class="sm:mx-auto sm:w-full sm:max-w-sm">
      <h2 class="mt-10 text-center text-2xl font-bold leading-9 tracking-tight text-gray-900">test page</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="mt-10 sm:mx-auto sm:w-full sm:max-w-sm">
      <div class="space-y-6">

        <div class="relative">
          <input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="floating_outlined" class="block px-2.5 pb-2.5 pt-4 w-full text-sm text-gray-900 bg-transparent rounded-lg border border-gray-300 appearance-none focus:outline-none focus:ring-0 focus:border-blue-600 peer" placeholder=" "
          />
          <label for="floating_outlined" class="absolute text-sm text-gray-500 duration-200 transform -translate-y-4 scale-75 top-2 z-10 origin-[0] bg-white px-2 peer-focus:px-2 peer-focus:text-blue-600  peer-placeholder-shown:scale-100 peer-placeholder-shown:-translate-y-1/2 peer-placeholder-shown:top-1/2 peer-focus:top-2 peer-focus:scale-75 peer-focus:-translate-y-4 start-1 rtl:!origin-right">My Floating Label (1)</label>
        </div>

        <div class="relative">
          <input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="floating_outlined" class="block px-2.5 pb-2.5 pt-4 w-full text-sm text-gray-900 bg-transparent rounded-lg border border-gray-300 appearance-none  focus:outline-none focus:ring-0 focus:border-blue-600 peer" placeholder=" "
            value="This is a test" />
          <label for="floating_outlined" class="absolute text-sm text-gray-500 duration-200 transform -translate-y-4 scale-75 top-2 z-10 origin-[0] bg-white px-2 peer-focus:px-2 peer-focus:text-blue-600  peer-placeholder-shown:scale-100 peer-placeholder-shown:-translate-y-1/2 peer-placeholder-shown:top-1/2 peer-focus:top-2 peer-focus:scale-75 peer-focus:-translate-y-4 rtl:!origin-right start-1">My Floating Label (2)</label>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="mt-8 text-center text-sm text-gray-500">
        <a>Switch To:</a>
        <a id="lng" class="font-semibold leading-6 text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-500 cursor-pointer" onclick="switchLang()">RTL</a>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Check my update please, still not working, what else have u changed to force it working?

Comment: You're still applying `direction` style on the `<html>` element. You'd want to switch the `dir` attribute of the `<html>` element, not apply `direction` style for the `rtl:` Tailwind variant to match: `document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].dir = 'rtl';`

Comment: But that was your answer which I copied!

Comment: I don't know what to say - the JavaScript section for your edited version does not have the updated JavaScript in my solution.

Comment: Ok I can see the mistaken line now I'll try to work it out and see the results..

Comment: So multiple lines need to be changed not just JS also to add some classes and remove others! I didn't notice that in the answer, but it works it is the answer for me.